# How to edit table automatic width?

Tags: tables

How do I make the width not too big and how do I make the matrix appear at the center ? I copied this format from somewhere but i don't know how to edit it.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabu} to 1\textwidth {| X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |@{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
    k & $\pi$ & $\bm{\mu}$ & $\bm{S}$ \\ \hline
    1 & 0.865
      & [1.54   1.63    3.88]
      & $\begin{bmatrix} .0187 & .0043 & .0101 \\ .0043 & .0104 & .0152 \\ .0101 & .0152 & .1814 \end{bmatrix}$ \\[5ex] \hline
    2 & 0.135
      & [1.76   0.66    0.84]
      & $\begin{bmatrix} .0187 & .0043 & .0101 \\ .0043 & .0104 & .0152 \\ .0101 & .0152 & .1814 \end{bmatrix}$ \\[5ex] \hline
    \end{tabu}
    \caption{Maximum Likelihood Estimates of the component parameters.}
    \label{estimatedparameters}
    \end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have special reason to use `tabu` package for table?

Comment: Off-topic: Don't embed a `table` environment inside a `center` environment. If the tabular material inside the `table` needs to be centered, provide a `\centering` instruction immediately after `\begin{table}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you persist to use `tabu`, than try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{bm,mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\tabulinesep =_3pt^3pt
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {| X[1,c,m] | X[1,c,m] | X[2,c,m] | X[3,c,m,$$]|}
    \hline
k   & $\pi$ & $\bm{\mu}$        & \bm{S}            \\ 
    \hline
1   & 0.865 & [1.54 1.63 3.88]  & \begin{bmatrix}
            .0187 & .0043 & .0101 \\
            .0043 & .0104 & .0152 \\
            .0101 & .0152 & .1814 \end{bmatrix}     \\
    \hline
2   & 0.135 & [1.76 0.66 0.84]  & \begin{bmatrix}
            .0187 & .0043 & .0101 \\
            .0043 & .0104 & .0152 \\
            .0101 & .0152 & .1814 \end{bmatrix}     \\
    \hline
    \end{tabu}
\caption{Maximum Likelihood Estimates of the component parameters.}
    \label{estimatedparameters}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
\begin{tabu} to 1\textwidth {| X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |@{}m{0pt}@{}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}
```

This will centre-align all of the table contents, without spacing them out, and make sure the matrices fit into the last column.